# Unset session in php

Tags: php

I want to know that how to unset session in this method.

**Here is my code**

```
<?php include  ('common/config.php');
    
     session_start();
     $curLocation =  $_SESSION['curLocation'];
     if ($curLocation == '') 
     { 
         $curLocation='london';
     }
 ?>
```

I am doing like this

```
<?php
  session_destroy();  
  if ($curLocation='london') 
  {    
      unset($_SESSION['curLocation']);
  } 
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [session destroy in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412783/session-destroy-in-php)

Comment: still not working after i change my code

Comment: Use all caps characters in session variable `$_SESSION`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay OP does that already

Comment: @ArslanKiyani, whats happening? are you getting any errors? The two code snippets you shows above is in the same page?

Comment: I have two country name is london and lagos. I want when I click on lagos country name then session of london will be deestroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `=` and not one

```
<?php
  session_destroy();  
  if ($curLocation == 'london') //here
  {    
      unset($_SESSION['curLocation']);
  }
?>
```

What you are doing is assigning a value to `$curLocation` instead of comparing it to something

Answer (score 2):

Please check your code is not right

Your wrong code

```
 if ($curLocation='london')
```

Correct

```
if ($curLocation=='london')
```

Comment: hmm. try this $_SESSION['curLocation'] = ''; where you want to clear your session it will work surely

Answer (score 1):

To destroy a session all you need to do is:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy(); 
?>
```

And you don't need to unset anything as you're destroying it anyway.

However if you want to only unset a specific variable, you do that with:

```
unset($_SESSION['variableName']);
```

Also, This code:

```
 $curLocation =  $_SESSION['curLocation'];
 if($curLocation=='') 
 { 
     $curLocation='london';
 }
```

can be written as:

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['curLocation']) ) {
    $_SESSION['curLocation'] = 'london';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest version:

```
unset($_SESSION['varname']);
```

or

```
session_destroy();
```

If you want to create a LOGOUT script, try this:

```
// Clear session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if(ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Destroy the session.
session_destroy();

// Set message
echo "Signing out..";

// Redirect to login page
header("Refresh:3; url=login.php", true, 303);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unset session value in php use session_destroy() function and if you want to click a logout button then session value is destroyed and redirect to login page, so follow this code and try it in your web application:

```
<?php   
session_start();
session_unset($_SESSION['user_id']); //to ensure you are using same session
session_destroy(); //destroy the session
echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>"; //to redirect back to "index.php" after logout
exit();
?>
```